# How can i play vimeo video in VIMVideoPlayer URL restricted

Tags: ios, swift, vimeo, vimeo-ios

i have integrated VIMVideoPlayer from [https://github.com/vimeo/VIMVideoPlayer]
and tried to play https://vimeo.com/342236564 but it showing error message

here is my code

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.vimPlayer.player.isLooping = true
    self.vimPlayer.player.disableAirplay()
    self.vimPlayer.setVideoFillMode(AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue)

    self.vimPlayer.delegate = self

    playVideo()
}

func playVideo(){
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://vimeo.com/342236564")!)
        self.vimPlayer.player.setPlayerItem(playerItem)
    self.vimPlayer.player.play()

}
```

and i have restricted to only one domain. How can i get the video in my mobile apps

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: URL not found, the thing i have enabled "Where can your videos be embedded?" section for only 2 domains

Answer (score 1):

First off, look at the top of that GitHub page:

> ⚠️⚠️⚠️ This library has been deprecated and will be removed in the
>   future. Use [PlayerKit](https://github.com/vimeo/PlayerKit) instead. ⚠️⚠️⚠️

Second, both VIMVideoPlayer and PlayerKit are intended to make it easier for developers to play back video files -- you are providing a link to a webpage (https://vimeo.com/342236564) instead of a link to a video file (like http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi).

Finally, note that a Vimeo video's playback privacy and embed privacy settings only apply to the video when played on vimeo.com or when using the Vimeo embedded player. Those privacy settings do not apply to direct video file links -- anyone or any service with those video file links will have access to them. More information here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567